# Align camera's viewing direction to view in a particular direction

Tags: graphics, 3d, computer-vision, perspectivecamera, projective-geometry

I am working with a point cloud and multiple images. 
I know the camera's intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. What I want is to find the 
rotation matrix which will rotate my camera(without changing the position) to view in
a certain direction. More specifically, I would fit a plane to the point cloud and 
then I want to align my camera's viewing direction to view perpendicular to the plane(without 
changing its position).

Accordingly, I would find the homography transform for the image also, given the rotation matrix for the camera.

Please someone help me with this.

Comment: Can't you just create a new view-matrix for the camera, which uses the desired position/direction or do you need to have the rotation matrix? Btw are you using some libraries like Direct3D or OpenGL ?

Comment: No, I am not using any libraries. I want to get the rotation matrix, so that I can project the point cloud on the image to get the depth map corresponding to the image. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Let `dir1` be the current direction of the camera and `dir2` be target direction of the camera. Calculate normalized direction vectors:

```
d1 = dir1 / |dir1|
d2 = dir2 / |dir2|
```

We want to get a matrix which rotates from `d1` to `d2`. In other words, this matrix should perform rotation by an angle of `theta` about an axis in the direction of `u`, where:

```
u = (d1 x d2) / |d1 x d2|       <-- normalized cross product of d1 and d2
sin(theta) = |d1 x d2|          <-- the length of the cross product
cos(theta) = d1 * d2            <-- dot product of d1 and d2
```

Finally, we plug the above values into this formula (you can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)), obtaining the requested matrix:

[image: rotation matrix]

Comment: Hi Miloszmaki,

I got your response. I have a simpler doubt. We don't have to translate the camera back to origin to perform this rotation, or do we?

Comment: If your camera is not at the origin, then you have to perform the rotation first, and then do the translation to the target position.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` is the center of the image then say `c = [a,b,1]` (this is considering the image is a 2D image).

Now you have the intrinsic parameter matrix `K` and extrinsic-Rotational matrix `R`

We can find the direction in this style:

```
temp_X = inverse(K) * c
temp_X = transpose(R) * temp_X
direction = temp_X / norm(temp_X)

final direction = t - direction
```

I don't know whether this is completely right but you can give it a try.